# How do I find which records DON'T match in TSQL?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I start out with a list of event types

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[jch_test_EventTypeName](
    [EventTypeName] [varchar](50) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

with the data

```
EventTypeName
"Event Type A"
"Event Type B"
"Event Type C"
"Event Type D"
```

And also a list of events for a patient

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[jch_test_Events](
    [PatID] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [EventTypeName] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [EventTime] [varchar](50) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

With data that looks like this

```
PatID   EventTypeName   EventTime
"abc"   "Event Type A"  01:00
"abc"   "Event Type B"  01:05
"abc"   "Event Type C"  01:07
"xyz"   "Event Type A"  01:00
"xyz"   "Event Type C"  01:07
```

How do I form a tsql query to see which Patients are missing "Event Type D"?

Comment: Please provide the query you are currently trying unsuccessfully to get the results

Comment: check sql exists clause, you could also use a left join

Comment: More specifically, `select distinct ... where not exists ...`.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT DISTINCT PatID
FROM jch_test_Events
WHERE PatId NOT IN (SELECT PatId FROM jch_test_Events WHERE EventTypeName = 'Event Type D')
```

Simply do a subselect with your "excluding" conditional

Answer (score 2):

This should also work

```
select distinct PatID from [dbo].[jch_test_Events]
except 
select distinct PatID from [dbo].[jch_test_Events]
where EventTypeName = 'Event Type D'
```

Comment: This is my goto in these cases. This and INTERSECT when doing data cleanup.